# Emacs xml mode indent with tabs

Tags: xml, emacs, indentation, sgml

i desperately try to make my emacs xml (sgml?) mode indent with tabs instead of spaces.
What i tried so far:

```
(defun my-xml-hook ()
  (setq c-tab-always-indent t
        tab-width 4
        indent-tabs-mode t) ; use tabs for indentation
  (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
)
(add-hook 'xml-mode-hook 'my-xml-hook)
(defun local-sgml-mode-hook
  (setq fill-column 70
        indent-tabs-mode t
        next-line-add-newlines nil
        sgml-indent-data t)
  (auto-fill-mode t)
  (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
  )
(add-hook 'psgml-mode-hook '(lambda () (local-psgml-mode-hook)))
```

Nothing works though, indentation will still happen with 2 spaces (emacs23 and emacs24) when editing *.xml files.

Note that i also have

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

in my .emacs file, but the hook should be called afterwards so this should be overridden.

How can i force emacs to indent with tabs in *.xml files? Why are my hooks not working?

Comment: `c-tab-always-indent` is for C/C++/Java. Since xml doesn't inherit them, I don't think it will work

Comment: there's equivalent `tab-always-indent` var that you should use

Comment: @abo-abo: tab-always-indent will always insert a tab when hitting tab. However i want _auto-indentation_ using tabs, such that if the indentation is already correct and i hit TAB, nothing happens. For inserting tabs manually i can always use C-q TAB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(c-)tab-always-indent` controls what hitting the TAB key does, not what is inserted.

Setting `indent-line-function` to `insert-tab` will make you lose the smart indentation of the mode.

If you are using a modern emacs, chances are you are using nxml-mode instead of xml-mode.  In that case `nxml-mode-hook` should be the one where you should do `(setq indent-tabs-mode t)`.

If you are using default sgml mode, `sgml-mode-hook` should be the one where you should do `(setq indent-tabs-mode t)` should be done (in your snippet you are using `psgml-mode-hook`)

(and tab-always-indent and indent-line-function could be leave in their default states)

**EDIT**

To summarize conversation below: variable `nxml-child-indent` should not be less than `tab-width`.

(and since default emacs values for those variables are 2 and 8, imho configuring emacs to indent XML using tabs in emacs is harder than it should be)

Comment: You are right, I use nxml-mode. Your solution does not seem to work, though. Even if I run eval-expression: `(setq indent-tabs-mode t)` right in the xml buffer indentation is still performed with 2 spaces.

Comment: The issue with sgml and nxml indentations is that they use indent-to.  This function will use spaces when tabs don't fit.   So you should check that `sgml-basic-offset` and `tab-width` are configured in a way they match (both to 4, for instance), and that previous lines are indented in multiples of that amount.

Comment: I set both variables to 4 and started indentation one line below a line starting at the very left, still 2 spaces indent :(

Comment: Try also increasing `nxml-child-indent`

Comment: Thanks - this variable worked! All i need to make it align with tabs in *.xml (emacs 24) is the following code in .emacs: `(defun my-indent-func ()
  (setq nxml-child-indent 4)
)
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook 'my-indent-func)
` . Problem solved - thanks jualeon

Answer (score 4):

It took me quite a while to get `nxml-mode` to use tabs.  I ended up using `smart-tabs-mode`, which offers a concise solution.  For what it's worth, here is the configuration that I finally settled on:

```
;; indentation using smart-tabs-mode
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(smart-tabs-insinuate 'c 'c++ 'java 'javascript 'cperl 'python 'ruby 'nxml)

;; nxml-mode
(setq 
    nxml-child-indent 4
    nxml-attribute-indent 4
    nxml-slash-auto-complete-flag t)
```

You don't actually need to set `nxml-slash-auto-complete-flag`, but it gets you auto end-tag completion, which is really nice.